# NoMethodError when using Refinements in an ActiveRecord Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinements

Ruby: 2.3.7

Rails: 4.2.10

I have the following implementation where I want to use Refinements to add a method to  String class

```
module StringExtensions
  refine String do
    def numeric?
      str = String.new(self)

      (/\A\d+\z/ =~ str) == 0
    end
  end
end

class ShippingAddress < Address
  using StringExtensions

  # ...

  private

  def normalise_address_1
    return unless address_1.numeric?

    self.address_1 = "Calle #{address_1}"
  end
end
```

As evident `numeric?` is the refined method on String class.

However, I fails with `NoMethodError`

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `numeric?' for "20":String
from (pry):1:in `normalise_address_1'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: is the module placed in a separate file? which directory?

Comment: Before I had the refinement under `lib` and I `require` it in the class. It didnt work. For now, I am debugging by having it in the same file.

I dont think this is a visibility issue as `using StringExtensions` worked in both cases

Comment: I just quickly tested this in my rails project and it worked for me. I placed that module under a new file in `config/initializers` directory

Comment: `Refinements` do not fall under `initializers` for me. Anyways I have it in the same class for now. 

I am looking for feedback on why its working in the first place

Comment: It works for me (outside of Rails.)